# Couldn't access Keycloak authentification in a server

Tags: angular, server, keycloak

I'm building an angular application secured with keycloak 10.0.2, i've deployed it in a server, and when i try to access it i can't reach Keycloak login page, here is my configuration

```
keycloak: {
    keycloakUrl: 'http://servername:8085/auth',
    realm: 'app',
    clientId: 'myapp',
    redirectUri: 'http://servername:8083/myapp'
  }
```

Should i put `http://localhost:8085/auth` or `http://servername:8085/auth`, or should i change localhost in keycloak to the servername, since keycloak is pre configured to localhost.

I found that i have to enable remote access and change `standalone.xml,` i changed it but i still get the error :

```
<interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:0.0.0.0}"/>
</interface>
<interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:0.0.0.0}"/>
</interface>
```

[image]

And below the log when starting Keycloak :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment, but I don't have the 'priveledge' to do that yet.

First It would be helpful if you could provide the logs of the keycloak server, when you start keycloak it should tell you the address it is listening on, make sure that it really is `http://0.0.0.0:8085/`, especially since 8085 is not the default port for keycloak.
If it really is listening on `http://0.0.0.0:8085/` then we would need more information about your network setup, for example: Are both, keycloak and your angular app, running on the same Server? Can you use netstat on the keycloak server to confirm that it is listening on the specified port?

Here is an example of Keycloak showing it's IP and port, look for this line
[image]

Comment: i've added the log in the question, i think it starting on 0.0.0.0:9990, this address opens up the wildfly server page

Comment: how can i use netstat?

Comment: Hey, I can acctually comment now, thank you.
First yea, that' wilfdly listening on 9990, further up it should also list the keycloak ip and port.
The default should be 8080 for http and 8443 for https, did you try to connect to these?

And the use of netstat will depend on your distro. you can try `netstat -tulpn`or  `ss -tulpn`

Comment: @BillyDEKAR I stumbled upon this answer in the course of investigating [*another question of yours*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64025546/4465539). You don't strike me as the „[*Help Vampire*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem)“ type. So is it safe to assume that the reason you didn't *Accept* this, is because it didn't solve the problem you laid out in your question? If you could share how you eventually solved the issue in this question, those details could go a long way in helping to find a solution to your more recent Angular/Spring Boot/Keycloak Q.

Comment: i didn't accept it because, the solution to my question was that the flow in port 8085 was  blocked by the company infra department